# How to put data from columns with same names in the same column, under the other

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I need to select the largest id from each table and unite them all into a single table, example: largest company id 1, largest company id 2 and largest company id 3 + your 'nser' and 'rssi' data and put these lines one under the other. I do not know how to do it.

in the image duplicate columns appear, what I need is only 1 column of each attribute but a row of data for each table. Example: 1 column 'id', 1 column 'nser', 1 column 'rssi', as a result I need = 1 row from table 1 with data id, nser and rssi, 1 row from table 2 with data id, nser and rssi and 1 row from table 3 with id, nser and rssi data

1 column for each duplicate attribute + 1 row for each table

Comment: Please update your question to include source data and the expected output, based on that source data (as editable text tables, not images). However, what I expect you are looking for is the UNION construct, rather than JOIN

Comment: I tried to transcribe what I would like as output: in the image duplicate columns appear, what I need is only 1 column of each attribute but a row of data for each table. Example: 1 column 'id', 1 column 'nser', 1 column 'rssi', as a result I need = 1 row from table 1 with data id, nser and rssi, 1 row from table 2 with data id, nser and rssi and 1 row from table 3 with id, nser and rssi data

Comment: I expect output: 1 column 'id' 1 column 'nser' 1 column 'rssi', with output data: column id= 3426 and 3416, column nser="12089/1" and "260 R17047", column rssi= -42 and -4

Comment: Hi - please update your question rather than adding additional information in comments. If you want to know how to format data as tables then this post should help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: Please update your question and replace images with text. See [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). BTW we cannot see that your results as the image only shows 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

To have one row from each table, a `UNION ALL` of both sub-queries will do:

```sql
with a as (select id, nser, rssi from cliente1_120891 where nser = '12089/1' order by id desc limit 1),
b as (select id, nser, rssi from cliente2_260R17047 order by id desc limit 1)
select id, nser, rssi from a 
union all
select id, nser, rssi from b;
```

Result:

```
id  |nser      |rssi|
----+----------+----+
3426|12089/1   | -42|
3416|260 R17047|  -4|
```